# Error declaring a parameter constructor in a c++ class

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, syntax-error

Consider the stretch of code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::endl;

class SuperPower{
private:
    string name;
    int category;
public:
    string getName(){return name;}
    int getCategory(){return category;}
    SuperPower(string name, int category){
            this->name = name;
            this->category = category;
    }
};

class Person{
private:
    string name, nameRealLife;
    SuperPower **powers;
    SuperPower *powers2;
    int nPowers;
protected:
    Person(string name, string nameRealLife){
            this->name = name;
            this->nameRealLife = nameRealLife;
            powers = new SuperPower*[4];
            powers2 = new SuperPower[4]("",0);
            nPowers = 0;
    }
public:
    ~Person(){
            delete []powers;
    }
    Person(const Person& p){
            name = p.name;
            nameRealLife = nameRealLife;
            powers = new SuperPower*[4];
            nPowers = p.nPowers;
        for (int i=0;i<nPowers;i++)
            powers[i] = p.powers[i];

    }
    string getName(){
        return name;
    }
    bool addSuperPower(SuperPower &sp){
            if (nPowers>=4)
                return false;
            powers[nPowers++] = &sp;
            return true;
    }
    virtual double getTotalPower(){
        double totalPower = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<nPowers;i++){
            totalPower += powers[i]->getCategory();
        }
        return totalPower;
    }
};
...
```

My professor asked to solve a Objected Oriented Problem and I am struggling with the compiler to finish it because of this line:

```
powers2 = new SuperPower[4]("",0);
```

Trying to compile the code results in **error: parenthesized initializer in array new [-fpermissive]
     powers2 = new SuperPower4;**

Why is it wrong? Isn't it just definning the constructor's parameters? Why does it happen? How should I fix it?

Comment: Use `std::vector`,

Answer (score 1):

Do not use raw pointers. Use `std::vector`. It makes the life easier.

```
std::vector<SuperPower> powers2; // declaration
...
powers2(4, SuperPower("",0)),    // in constructors's initialisation list
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it work by using: `powers2 = new SuperPower[4]{{"", 0},{"", 0},{"", 0},{"", 0}};` instead of `powers2 = new SuperPower[4]("",0);` **but don't do this**, instead I insist you on using `std::vector` like this:

```
std::vector<Superpower> powers2;
```

and then in ctor:

```
powers2(4, Superpower("", 0));
```